# Laplace transform problem RL circuit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm having trouble solving an RL circuit using the Laplace Transform.

There's just a 2H inductor in series with a 5M ohm resistor.  The inductor is initially charged to 1.25A.

So... Here's what I've done:
$$
v_L(t) = v_R(t)\\
2i_L'(t) = 5Mi_L(t)
$$
Now taking the Laplace Transform,
$$
2(I_L(s)s - 1.25) = 5M I_L(s)\\
2.5 = 2I_L(s)s - 5M I_L(s)\\
2.5 = I_L(s)(2s - 5M)\\
I_L(s) = \frac{2.5}{2s-5M}\\
I_L(s) = \frac{1.25}{s-2.5M}
$$
Now taking the inverse Laplace transform,
$$
i_L(t) = 1.25e^{2.5Mt}
$$
This answer is wrong though, and there should be negative
$$
i_L(t) = 1.25e^{-2.5Mt}
$$

For the life of me, I can't work out where that negative comes from in the maths.

I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Oh, I should add that the $M$ is Mega (so $10^6$).

Comment: For the system you wrote at the beginning your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your conventions.

Either take $v_R = v_L$, in which case $i_R = -i_L$. This would be the usual convention (ie, current 'enters' the device through the $+$ terminal).

Or you could take $i_R = i_L$, in which case you will need to take $v_R = -v_L$.

In your problem above, you have, in effect, taken a negative resistance (or a negative inductance, of course). It might help to draw the circuit graph when conventions are not obvious.